# Why Node.js Express was passed in different variables through middle-wear router, but always comes out the same result by different URLs

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I am planning to access following two URLs, and trying to process **2 URLs** with **one log controller** through **a log router**

- /buy/:id/log
- /sale/:id/log

Previously, the log controller was linked with 'buy' and 'sell' router files, and works fine.
After adding log router file as a middle-wear, result always shows same result, no matter which URL was used.

I dont know if it is **Express error, or JS error**

---

Code concept:

1. route('/buy') or route('/sell')
2. route('/:id/log') and pass in BuyModel / SellModel
3. Process request

---

**Simplified code:**

In index.js

```
app.use('/buy', require('/routes/buy.js'))
app.use('/sell', require('/routes/sell.js'))
```

In 'buy.js' router file:

```
router.use('/:id/log', require('./log.js')(BuyModel))
```

In 'sell.js' router file:

```
router.use('/:id/log', require('./log.js')(SellModel))
```

In 'log.js' router file:

```
module.exports = function(model){
  router.route('/')
    .get(fetchLogs(model))
  return router
}
```

In 'log' controller file

```
exports.fetchLogs = model => (req, res) => {
  console.log (model)
}
```

---

*But result always show BuyModel*
Suspecting if due to buy.js and sell.js are pre-loaded and model param was replaced.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Have you tried logging the path in the log router? Like `console.log(req.originalUrl)` so you can see if it's /buy or /sell. I suspect maybe the BuyModel and SellModel are the same?

Comment: Log router shows different and correct path. BuyModel and SellModel are different model obj

Answer (score 0):

Solved by passing in router from buy.js and sell.js router files

```js
router.use('/:id/log', require('./log.js')(express.Router(), BuyModel))
```